# Extract metadata with arcpy from orthoimagery

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, metadata, orthophoto, error-000816

I'm very new to ArcGIS, and GIS is general.  I am trying to build a script that will extract metadata from orthoimagery .tifs. Below is my test code to see if I can get the metadata from one file. It is basically the code from ESRI's docs on arcpy and the metadata toolbox.

```
import arcpy
from os import path
from arcpy import env    
env.workspace = path.normpath("E:/RESOURCES/TEST_RESOURCES/Pasquotank/TIF/data")    
dir = arcpy.GetInstallInfo("desktop")["InstallDir"]    
translator = dir + path.normpath("Metadata/Translator/ESRI_ISO2ISO19139.xml")    
arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion(path.normpath("E:/RESOURCES/TEST_RESOURCES/Pasquotank/TIF/data/OC6i0_37_000_20793902_20100411R1.tif"), translator)
```

When I run this is get the following error.

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000816: The tool is not valid.
Failed to execute (ExportMetadata).
```

I've tried just using the file name as the first parameter in the ExportMetadata_conversion(), and got the same error.

When I run the tool from ArcCatalog, I get results.  So, I'm stuck. I am using ArcGIS 10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: below is a wrong solution. Correct solution linked to here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/14848

It looks like you are missing an output file in your parameters.

```
arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion(path.normpath("E:/RESOURCES/TEST_RESOURCES/Pasquotank/TIF/data/OC6i0_37_000_20793902_20100411R1.tif"), translator, {Output_File})
```

If I understand the Esri documentation correctly, the output_file is really only optional if your input is a standalone XML file.

Comment: Same result: `arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion(
    path.normpath("E:/RESOURCES/TEST_RESOURCES/Pasquotank/TIF/data/OC6i0_37_000_20793902_20100411R1.tif"), translator,
    path.normpath("E:/RESOURCES/TEST_RESOURCES/Pasquotank/TIF/test.xml"))` Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Your initial code works for me using a generic .tif. Note: I'm using ArcGIS 10.3. Have you tried with any other .tif files?

Comment: Also, check this thread if you haven't already: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/14848